# How to remove portions of Web page title using Javascript

Tags: javascript, userscripts, page-title

I'm new at this Javascript stuff, so please excuse my basic question. I'm trying to find a way to remove some portion of a web page title using Javascript in a userscript. Take for example the title of this page:

> How to remove portions of Web page title using Javascript - Stack Overflow

I want to yank out the '-' and Website name so that it becomes:

> How to remove portions of Web page title using Javascript

I know how to change the entire title using `document.title = "new title";`, but that's about the closest I can get. Can someone please help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
document.title.substr(0,document.title.lastIndexOf("-"));
```

It removes everything from the last occurrence of "-".

http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/TA69F/